# CSS Menu changes

Tags: css, drupal-8

I built this in Drupal8 using a Zymphonies theme, and was able to do almost everything I wanted, except for a few CSS things I can't figure out. The site is [here](http://dev-astro-mktg.pantheonsite.io/), and I need:

- To get rid of the white 1px border around the dropdown menus (see /services). I can't find where that is coming.

[image: border]

- Only have the black background on the dropdown **only**, not the entire navbar. Kind of dark I know, sorry.

Like this:

[image: bg]

Not this:

[image: no bg]

Comment: Is the `ul` style inlined or injected from a js script?

Comment: I have edited the answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following changes

```
ul#main-menu li {
    background: none;
}

ul#sm-14746145032132822-2 {
    background: black;
}
```

your issue will be solved

Comment: Hmm. That removed the black background from the submenus and the navbar. I just want the submenus black.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;` to `border: 1px solid black;` to fix your first issue, that's in your custom-media.css file on line 40:

```
 .menu-base-theme ul {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
  }
```